# PL/SQL transitive relation (bidirectiobal)

Tags: plsql

I need to find the transitive relation of the nodes.Nodes can be connected unidirectional or bidirectionally. Below is the sample table.

```
TABLE ITEM_TABLE
Item       Rel_Item     Bi_Direction
Z             Y              Y
Y             X              Y
X             A              Y
A             B              N
B             C              Y
A             D              Y
D             E              Y
E             F              N
M             N              N
N             O              N
```

Expected result

```
Item        Rel_Item       Bi_Direction
A             B               N
A             C               N                                                       
A             D               Y
A             E               Y
A             F               N
B             C               Y
D             E               Y
D             F               N
E             F               N
M             N               N
N             O               N

-> unidirectional
<-> bidirectional
case 1: A->B<->C
      because A to B is unidirectional , A to C is unidirectional
case 2: A <->D<->E->F
         A to E is bidirectional
         A to F is unidirectional because E to F is unidirectional.
```

On general, A node is unidirectional connected, if either parent or current node is unidirectional connected. I need to write the PL/SQL code for finding the transitive relation and bidirectional  or unidirectional.

Can someone please help.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_result
  IS
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT ITEM
    FROM 
        ITEM_TABLE

BEGIN
   FOR c IN c_result             
   LOOP

        DECLARE CURSOR INSIDE IS
            SELECT DISTINCT REL_ITEM, BI_DIRECTION,
            FROM ITEM_TABLE 
            start with ITEM = c.ITEM
            connect by nocycle prior REL_ITEM = ITEM;

        BEGIN
            FOR cin_res IN INSIDE
            LOOP
                INSERT INTO RESULTANT_ITEM_TABLE
                VALUES(c.ITEM, cin_res.REL_ITEM, cin_res.BI_DIRECTOIN);

                COMMIT;
            END LOOP;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I am trying to get the items. For each item find then nodes reachable. Insert item and related Items into resultant table. How to process the bi_directional field.

Comment: I believe your explanation of "unidirectional" in the output is incorrect (incomplete) - otherwise I am misunderstanding this and you will need to clarify. Take **case 2** in your post. A and F can still be connected bi-directionally, by a path different from A-D-E-F. For example, there could be uni-directional links from F to H and then from H to A. Isn't it, then, true that F can be reached from A, and also A can be reached from F (by a **different** path), and then A and F are bi-directionally linked? If not, you need to explain "bi-directional linked" in more detail.

Comment: The problem statement is find all the reachable child  nodes from every item , If in the path from node to any reachable node is 'N' then the final bidirection should be 'N'.

Comment: The problem statement is find all the reachable child  nodes from every item , If in the path from node to any reachable node is 'N' then the final bidirection should be 'N'. From A , the reachable nodes are A- B N, A-C via  A-B-C N because in the path A-B is 'N', A- D 'Y', A-E via A-D-E 'Y' because A-D and D-E are 'Y'. A-F 'N'  because in the path A-D-E-F,  E-F is 'N'.

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter one link which is unidirectional on the way to the next node, you can consider the whole path unidirectional. However this works only in **tree structures**, where you can reach all the nodes only in one way.

So the following solution will work in your example, but won't in graphs.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_items IS
    SELECT DISTINCT item
        FROM item_table
    ORDER BY item;

BEGIN
   FOR rec_item IN c_items LOOP

       DECLARE 
         CURSOR c_tree IS
            SELECT item, rel_item, bi_direction, LEVEL
                FROM item_table
            START WITH item = rec_item.item
                CONNECT BY 
                    NOCYCLE PRIOR rel_item = item ;
          connected VARCHAR(1) := 'Y';

        BEGIN
            FOR rec_tree IN c_tree
            LOOP            
                IF rec_tree.LEVEL = 1 THEN
                    connected := 'Y';
                END IF;

                IF rec_tree.bi_direction = 'N' THEN  
                    connected := 'N';
                END IF;

                INSERT INTO result_item_table VALUES (rec_item.item, rec_tree.rel_item, connected);                 

            END LOOP;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

On the other hand if you need an algorithm which will work in graphs then you must check before the `INSERT` if the record already exists in the `result_item_table` and if the bidirectional column is set to `'N'` and then `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine for the above scenario. Some duplicate rows are seen, if the node is reachable from someother path. Below is one such scenario: INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES('A','B','N');
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES('A','C','Y');
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES('A','D','N');
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES('B','D','Y');
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES('C','B','N');
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES('C','D','N');

Answer (score 0):

Changes been made for graphs. if item and rel_item is not found, insert it(handled by no_data_found exception).
If record is found, and connected is 'Y'.Update record with bidirection = 'Y' for the record. There can be two records for an item and rel_item with birection ='Y' and bidirection = 'N' from two different paths. If it is bidirection from any path item and rel_item are connected by 'Y'
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_items IS
    SELECT DISTINCT item
        FROM item_table
    ORDER BY item;

BEGIN
   FOR rec_item IN c_items LOOP

```
   DECLARE 
     CURSOR c_tree IS
        SELECT item, rel_item, bi_direction, LEVEL
            FROM item_table
        START WITH item = rec_item.item
            CONNECT BY 
                NOCYCLE PRIOR rel_item = item ;
      connected VARCHAR(1) := 'Y';
      i VARCHAR(2) := NULL;

    BEGIN
        FOR rec_tree IN c_tree
        LOOP            
            IF rec_tree.LEVEL = 1 THEN
                connected := 'Y';
            END IF;

            IF rec_tree.bi_direction = 'N' THEN  
                connected := 'N';
            END  IF;

            BEGIN
                select item INTO i 
                    FROM result_item_table 
                    WHERE item = rec_item.item  
                    AND  rel_item = rec_tree.rel_item;
                EXCEPTION /* If item not found insert */
                    WHEN no_data_found THEN 
                        INSERT INTO result_item_table VALUES (rec_item.item, rec_tree.rel_item, connected);

                IF i IS NOT NULL THEN
                    IF (connected = 'Y')
                    /* If item record id found and is N, there is one more path from which it is 'Y'
                       then update it to 'Y'*/
                    THEN
                        UPDATE result_item_table
                        SET bi_direction = connected
                        WHERE  item = rec_item.item  and  rel_item = rec_tree.rel_item;
                    END IF;
                END IF;

            END;
   END LOOP;
 END;
END LOOP;
```

END;

Comment: For some items connect by nocycle yields millions of records and takes days to process it. Procedure doesnot terminate at all. the number of records inserted to result_item_table  remains in the same state.After inserting few records into result_item_table   neither rows are inserted into result table nor procedure terminates.